# "Connection: Keep-Alive, close" as Response Headers

Tags: .htaccess, keep-alive

The question that I have might be pretty basic, but I can't find any solution. I'm trying to make keep-alive works, but it seem as if it was impossible as long as I get "Connection: keep-alive, close" as Response Headers.

I have the following code in my .htaccess, but it doesn't make any change:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>
```

What can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are getting both keep-alive and close because you need to edit this at the server conf level (ie: your vhost or httpd.conf)

If you simply do this through .htaccess it'll append the keep-alive to the close coming from your .conf.  If you have access to the confs, try to update it to the following:

```
KeepAlive On
KeepAliveTimeout 15
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
```